# From a security standpoint should I add my user to the sudoers file or not?

Tags: security, sudo, users, root

I'm wondering what's best practice from a security standpoint: should I add my user to the /etc/sudoers file on my single-user computer or rather just leave %sudo in there?

Would this cause any problems or would I have to open the console as root everytime I execute something requiring root priviliges?

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so now I've learned that it's best to simply not create a root account during installation. Simply leave the root password empty as explained in the installer. (No need to edit the sudoers file afterwards.) Then use the `sudo` and `sudo -i` commands for anything that requires root priviliges.

Answer (score 2):

As  a security perspective there is no different between defining a single user in "sudoers" file or adding it to a group like "sudo", however the default and the best practice is to add anyone who needs to issue `sudo` to the "sudo" group or "wheel" on different distributions.

When do I have to add a single user to "sudoers" file? when that specific user needs some specific permissions for example he's only able to run a specific command from a specific machine under user "john" without the need of providing his password.

Now lets say we have a lot of users and they all need the same default `sudo` privilege, it's not logical to add all of them one by one to the sudoers file, right? what we should do is to add all of them to "sudo" group.

however in your case, only one user there is no different, if you want to be able to run commands using `sudo` then add your self to "sudo" group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a security problem.

`sudo` is just of way for an administrator to have quick root access without using a root shell.

Using the root shell all the time is dangerous, following are a few reasons.

You're logged as root = all applications are running with root privilegies -- every vulnerability in Firefox, Flash, OpenOffice etc. now can destroy your system, because possible viruses now have access everywhere. Yes, there are only few viruses for Ubuntu/Linux, but it's also because of good security and default unprivileged user.
It's not only about viruses -- small bug in an application could erase some system files or...

When your're logged as root, you can do everything -- the system won't ask! Do you want to format this disk? Ok, just one click and it's done, because you're root and you know what you're doing.

Thus, `sudo` was created, so that when root access is needed, it will only be the one command you use `sudo` with, which gets root access, you will not be permanently using the root shell.

Comment: What about `su`?

Comment: If you use `su`, you are in a root shell until you exit it(`CNTRL + D`). Which should be avoided, unless all your activity requires root privilege.

Comment: sudo **is** a security tool. It is simply the way to give elevated privileges without giving everyone involved the **only** root passowrd. Aditionally, it allows to change user (not only root) and control which programs could be executed.

Comment: None of this is relevant to the question. The alternative between running a shell as root vs running a one-off command as root is not mentioned in the question and is not relevant to the requested choice of sudo configuration.